# Can't download from home page

Tags: release-odin

I have tried to download the iso from the home page in both brave and firefox, Ubuntu and Windows and the button will not do anything, either paid or custom.

Answer (score 0):

Got stuck on this one too, but I just figured it out!
Just type 0 into the "custom" box and click "Download elementary OS".
If all goes well (which it really should), you should see a dialog prompting you to either do a direct download or download via magnet link.